# How to add label at center of three nodes and have it pointed to nodes respectively?

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, graphs, paths

In tikz I have three nodes as following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf, tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>= stealth, shorten >= 1pt,node distance = 3cm,semithick%, auto]

\tikzstyle{every state}=[draw = black,thick,fill = white]

\node[state] (p11) {$p_{1,1}$};

\node[state] (p12) [right of=p11] {$p_{1,2}$};

\coordinate (Middle) at ($(p11)!0.5!(p12)$);

\node[state] (t1) [below of=Middle] {$t_1$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And I want to add label at the center of nodes, then have the label pointed to each node. Like below:

[image]

How can I do it? Btw I don't have `auto` property enabled for `tikzpicture` because it will mess up my midway label within edge.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: full code updated

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post compilable examples, not just fragments.

Comment: Please add the `\documentclass{..}` line as well: it is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple modification:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [% \tikzstyle is deprecated - use \tikzset{} instead
    >= Stealth,
    shorten >= 1pt,
    node distance = 3cm,
    semithick,
    every state/.style={draw = black, thick, fill = white},
  ]
  \node[state] (p11) {$p_{1,1}$};
  \node[state] (p12) [right of=p11] {$p_{1,2}$};
  \coordinate (Middle) at ($(p11)!0.5!(p12)$);
  \node[state] (t1) [below of=Middle] {$t_1$};
  \node (here) at ($(t1)!1/2!(Middle)$) {My label};
  \path [->] (here) edge (p11) edge (p12) edge (t1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image: modification for label]

I've partially updated the syntax to use `arrows.meta` and avoid `\tikzstyle`. However, ideally, you would also use the `positioning` library and its syntax, too.